# about states of finite state machine

Tags: fsm

the question is let sigma =(1,2,3,$). I need to draw its  diagram which outputs 1 when sum is >_5. if it is over 5, the amount will be carried over.

Im wondering what would be the state in this case. Can I let A = ive seen 1 B=ive seen 2, C=ive see 3 and D = accepted state?

Comment: Your question says "when current sum is greater than or equal to 5". So you're going to need to keep track of what the current sum is; so you're going to need a different state for every different possible sum, and you're going to need a state transition for every combination of "I've just seen X and the sum of what I've seen since I last output a 1 is Y". Start drawing those out on a piece of paper and it should all become clear.

Comment: thank you for your comment :D. I've been thinking about it for a few minutes, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep track of the current sum. The only tool I have for this question is 'input/output' . Can you give me an example of such diagram?

Comment: Wait a minute! You have just changed the question and now your accepted states are those in which the sum is less than 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use just three states. Your FSM must, somehow, keep counting the current sum of the input values so far. The problem is that a FSM has no memory (that would be another kind of automata) so it has to be one state for every possible combination of numbers that evaluate to all possible sums.

That is: you need a state that means ("the current sum is 0").Let that state be state 0. That would be your initial state. Other states would be "the current sum is 1" (state 1), "the current sum is 2" (state 2), .... , "the current sum is 5" (state 5), "the current sum is 6" (state 6), etc (no, you won't need an inifinite number of states, as for example, from state 5, a transition with value 1 leads you again to the state 1.

From state 0, a transition with 1 leads you to state 1. Transition with 2, to state 2 and transition with 3 to state 3. Easy, isn't it?

From state 3, for example, a transition with 1 leads you to transition 4, Transition with 2 to state 5, which is an accept state, and transition with 3 to state 6, which is also an accepted state.

To put another example: from state 6, a transition with 1 leads you to... state 2. That's right: state 6 means that the current sum is 6, which exceeds 5 in 1. So this is like transition 1, but it is an accepted state, so transitions from state 6 go to the same places as transitions from state 1 would go. This will help you building your FSM.

In fact, the larger state number is determined by the largest value you can sum with 1,2 and 3 that overflows 5 for the first time. That would be 1+1+1+1+3 = 7. So you need to define from state 0 to state 7, and of course, a final state when $ is detected.

Comment: thank you! I drew the diagram and  there are too many arrows floating around back and forth in my diagram, so I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. In my diagram, for state 1, I have to transition over to state 2,3,4,5,6 and for state 2, i have to transition over to state 3,4,5,6 and so on. From state 6, I have to transition over to state 2,3,4 only. And the accepted state would be state 5 and 6 only. Am I correct?

Comment: Also, I have state 0 up to state 6 and + final state. I'm not sure why I need state 7. I thought I need only upto 6 because 6 is the first number that is greater than or equal to 5. Do I still need state 7?? I drew it with state 0 to state 7 and in this case state 5,6,7 become my accepted state.

Comment: No. From state 1, if "1" means that the current sum is 1, you have three transitions (not counting a transition to the final state if the sumbol is "$"): one if the symbol is 1, that goes to state 2. Another one if the symbol is 2, that goes to state 3, and another one if the symbol is 3, that would go to state 4, as these are the only possible symbols in your input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep track of the current sum. You just need to keep track of the total sum modulo 5.

One way of doing this is to let your state space be A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, and B0, B1, B2. If you enter an "A" state, you output 0, and if you enter a "B" state, you output 1.

Your state transitions depend on the next digit that you see. For example:

- If you are in A1, and the next digit you see is 2, you transition to A3, and output 0.
- If you are in A4, and the next digit you see is 1, you transition to B0, and output 1.
- If you are in B2, and the next digit you see is 1, you enter A3, and output 0.
- If you are in B2, and the next digit you see is 3, you enter B0, and output 1.

In general, suppose you are in state XY, where X is either A or B, and Y is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. Let D be the next digit you see. The next state you will enter will be X'Y', where:

- X' is A if D + Y < 5.
- X' is B if D + Y >= 5.
- Y' is D + Y modulo 5.